# Why my select onchange is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
            <select>
                <option onChange="filterProducts(this);">Select ...</option>
                <option onChange="filterProducts(this);">Samsung</option>
                <option onChange="filterProducts(this);">LG</option>
                <option onChange="filterProducts(this);">Sony</option>
                <option onChange="filterProducts(this);">Philips</option>
            </select>
```

Which should fire a js method but it simply does not fire:

```
function filterProducts(firedByControl){
   alert(fired);
}
```

For this button, calling the same js method, all works nice:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="filterProducts(this)" value="LCD">LCD</button>
```

Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: the onchange has to be on the `<select>` tag, not the options. Options don't "change".

Comment: Thanks to all, unbelieavable how easy it was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the onchange call on the  element.

```
 <select onChange="filterProducts(...);">
            <option>Select ...</option>
            <option>Samsung</option>
            <option>LG</option>
            <option>Sony</option>
            <option>Philips</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `onchange` to the select like below,

```
<select onchange="filterProducts">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `onchange` should be an attribute of the `<select>` element, not each `<option>`.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead `<select onchange="filterProducts(this);">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the onchange attribute on the `select`, not on the `option`.

By the way, you should probably do something like that using JQuery :

```
$("select").onChange(filterProducts);
```